# How to GeoJSON-encode a feature with many points where some properties of the member points are different

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have a db table with features like so

| fid | lng | lat | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14.5041 | 46.0434 | blue |
| 1 | 14.5367 | 45.8631 | red |
| 2 | 15.5041 | 44.0434 | mauve |
| 2 | 15.5367 | 43.8631 | pink |

I want to convert the above into GeoJSON. My first thought was to make it into a `FeatureCollection` of `MultiPoint` features since really, they are features, each with more than one or more points. Each `feature` has the same `fid` but may have additional properties, for example, `color`. The [GeoJSON spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946), however, says:

> The GeoJSON "geometry" and "properties" members define a Feature object.  FeatureCollection and Geometry objects, respectively, MUST NOT contain a "geometry" or "properties" member.

Any suggestions on how I could convert my table of features into GeoJSON? Of course, the easiest would be to simply create a separate point for each row even if they have the same `fid`, but is there a better way?

**update:** I guess I could encode it like so where `properties.other` is an array with properties for member points.

```json
const geojsonFeature = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPoint",
                "coordinates": [
                    [ 14.5041, 46.0434 ],
                    [ 14.5367, 45.8631 ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "fid": 1,
                "other": [
                    { "color": "blue" },
                    { "color": "red" },
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPoint",
                "coordinates": [
                    [ 15.5041, 44.0434 ],
                    [ 15.5367, 43.8631 ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "fid": 2,
                "other": [
                    { "color": "mauve" },
                    { "color": "pink" },
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

For one, I would like to provide the ability to click on a point and "highlight" all other points with the same `fid`, that is, from the same feature.

Any suggestion on how I could accomplish the above?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use `MultiPoint` feature in a case where each point has different properties. Just group together only points with the same properties, which means there will be features with the same `fid` value. Would that be a problem?

Comment: conceptually, my data is made of `MultiPoint` features. Each feature with a bunch of properties (such as `fid`, which happens to be a unique id), has one or more sub-features that have location data. So, the location data really belongs to these sub-features (points) which have their own properties as well. Using `MultiPoints` seems like the *right* thing to do. In my db, the features are in one table with sub-features in a related table linked by `fid`

Comment: If you do it this way, you'll have a problem of pairing marker with the right properties. When marker is created from multipoint feature, you don't have info which of the points (point index) is that in multipoint array. How will you know then which properties belong to it? Of course you could then use `enEachFeature` option to go through multipoint coordinates and pair them with markers, but that seems rather complicated.