# Highlight all GeoJSON multipoints of the same feature with a click in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, markers

**update:** I've got most of what I want working… clicking on a marker changes its icon and also opens a popup showing that marker's properties (from GeoJSON `feature.properties`). Clicking on the basemap resets the icon back to the original. But, what I haven't figured out is how to select all the members of a `multipoint` feature when any of its points is clicked. What I want is exactly as is happening in [this map on geojson.tools](https://geojson.tools/index.html). If I copy my example GeoJSON feature on that webpage, I can click on a point and all the points in that multipoint are highlighted. I can't figure out how to do that with LeafLet.

I have the following code that highlights a clicked marker by changing its icon. However, I would like to select *all* the markers of the same `multipoint` (for example, if I click on a marker with `fid: 0`, I want to "highlight" all the other points with `fid: 0`. And there should be a way to revert back to the original icon, perhaps after a set time period (I could use `setTimeout`) or if the user clicks on the map baselayer.

```js
var geojsonFeature = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPoint",
                "coordinates": [[14.50, 46.04], [14.53, 45.86]]
            },
            "properties": { "fid": 0 }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPoint",
                "coordinates": [[15.50, 44.04], [15.53, 43.86]]
            },
            "properties": { "fid": 1 }
        }
    ]
};

const iconNormal = L.icon({
    iconUrl     : '/img/treatment.svg',
    iconSize: [24, 24],
    iconAnchor: [12, 12],
});

const iconHighlighted = L.icon({
    iconUrl     : '/img/treatment-highlighted.svg',
    iconSize: [24, 24],
    iconAnchor: [12, 12],
});

L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
    pointToLayer: function(gp, latlng) {
        const marker = L.marker(latlng, { icon: iconNormal });
        const click = {
            'click': (e) => e.target.setIcon(iconHighlighted)
        };

        return marker.on(click);
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

My code feels very amateurish. Is there a better way? And how do I select other markers with the same `fid` and change their icons?

Comment: Seems duplicate of the following question: [How to GeoJSON-encode a feature with many points where some properties of the member points are different](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421731/how-to-geojson-encode-a-feature-with-many-points-where-some-properties-of-the-me). If you wan to add new/changed info, please edit the original question

Comment: no, the other question is the previous step to what I am asking in this one. The other question is about actually generating MultiPoint GeoJSON from a database table of latlng points where some properties may be different. This one is about interaction on the map given a GeoJSON (I am just using the same pseudo-fragment of GeoJSON for both questions)

Comment: But this question seem to be dependent on the result/answer to the previous question. Please ask one similar question at a time, so it will be clear what your current problem/question is.

Comment: no, they are related in that I am trying to solve them both, but they are separate problems. To reiterate: the other question is about generating GeoJSON on the server from data in a db table. This question is about interacting with a GeoJSON, specifically about selecting the different points of a multipoint feature

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution (see better one below) for this would be to create an array `markersByFid`, where each element is again and array of markers that have the same `fid` property and this is also the index of the array in the `markersByFid` array.

Each marker is at the creation given custom property `fid` with the value of `fid` property from feature. This value is then used at the marker click to get corresponding array of markers with the same `fid` value from `markersByFid` array. Icons can then be set for these markers.

At the same time value of `fid` is saved in the global `lastClickedFid`, so then on the map click outside markers, icons for the last clicked markers can be reset.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var markersByFid = [];
var lastClickedFid = null;

function clearLastClicked() {
  if (lastClickedFid != null) {
    markersByFid[lastClickedFid].forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setIcon(iconNormal);
    });
    lastClickedFid = null;
  }
}

L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
  pointToLayer: function(gp, latlng) {
    const marker = L.marker(latlng, { icon: iconNormal });
    marker.fid = gp.properties.fid;
    if (!markersByFid[gp.properties.fid]) {
      markersByFid[gp.properties.fid] = [];
    }
    markersByFid[gp.properties.fid].push(marker);
    const click = {
      'click': (e) => {
        var fid = e.target.fid;
        if (fid == lastClickedFid) return;
        clearLastClicked();
        markersByFid[fid].forEach(function(marker) {
          marker.setIcon(iconHighlighted);
        });
        lastClickedFid = fid;
      }
    }; 
    return marker.on(click);
  }
}).addTo(map);

map.on('click', function(evt) {
  clearLastClicked();
});
```

**EDIT:** After some thought there is a simpler solution by using `onEachFeature` option function, where layer parameter is actually a group layer, containing all the markers that come from one multipoint feature.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var lastClickedFeature = null;

function clearLastClicked() {
  if (lastClickedFeature != null) {
    lastClickedFeature.eachLayer(function(marker) {
      marker.setIcon(iconNormal);
    });
    lastClickedFeature = null;
  }
}

L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
  pointToLayer: function(gp, latlng) {
    const marker = L.marker(latlng, { icon: iconNormal });
    return marker;
  },
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function(evt) {
      if (evt.target == lastClickedFeature) return;
      clearLastClicked();
      evt.target.eachLayer(function(marker) {
        marker.setIcon(iconHighlighted);
      });
      lastClickedFeature = evt.target;
    });
  }
}).addTo(map);

map.on('click', function(evt) {
  clearLastClicked();
});
```